# Using Group By with Array[(String, Int)]

Tags: scala, group-by

Working on Scala and I have the following:

```
val file1 = Array(("test",2),("other",5));
val file2 = Array(("test",3),("boom",4));
```

Then I join the two arrays:

```
val toGether = file1.union(file2);
```

Finally want to produce a GroupBy that will produce the following:

```
Array(("test",(2,3)),("other",(5,0)),("boom",(0,4)))
```

is this possible?

Comment: What is the meaning of the two `0`s in your expected output ?

Comment: What should happen if you have 3 "test" keys and only 1 of any other keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, then what you want can be done with a following piece of code:

```
val file1 = Array(("test", 2), ("other", 5))
val file2 = Array(("test", 3), ("boom", 4))

val map1 = file1.toMap
val map2 = file2.toMap
val allKeys = map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet
val result: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = allKeys.map(k => (k, (map1.getOrElse(k, 0), map2.getOrElse(k, 0))))(scala.collection.breakOut)

println(result.mkString)
```

The idea is simple: convert both arrays to maps and create the resulting array using iteration over joined keyset. Note that this code does not preserved any order but I'm not sure if this is important and it makes code much simpler. Note also that this code requires the collections to fit into memory, actually several times. If `file1` and `file2` are actually contents of big files that do not fit into memory, much more complicated algorithm should be used.